# How to find the depth of a pixel using two x y and z coordinates

Tags: c++, math, line, zbuffer

I am working on z buffering with lines, and I am trying to find the depth of a certain pixel.
Here is my line drawing code:

```
void l(int x1, int y1, int z1, int x2, int y2, int z2, int cl)
{
    int deltax = x2 - x1; // The difference in the x's
    int deltay = y2 - y1; // The difference in the y's
    int m = deltay / deltax; // The slope of the line (with deltax > 0)
    for (int x = 0; x <= deltax; x++)
    {
        int y = m * x; // Calculate the y-value
        int xcalc = x + x1;
        int ycalc = round(y) + y1;
        color[xcalc][ycalc].c = cl; // Draw the current pixel
    }
}
```

and here is my struct and color variable:

```
struct distancecolor { //c = color, d = depth
    int c;
    float d;
};
distancecolor color[250][250];
```

d = depth of pixel and c = color of pixel, stored from 1-9, because it is a custom rendering engine.
All I want to do is take in x1, y1, and z1, and then use x2, y2, and z2 with an equation to find the distance from 0 to x, or the pixel being placed, on the line. Ask me for any other needed information.

Comment: FYI, in graphics terms `depth of a pixel` is the number of bits used to represent the pixel.  For example, you could have an RGB pixel with 4 bits for Red, 4-bits for Green and 4-bits for Blue, as compared to 8-bits R, 8-bits G and 8-bits B.  The 8 bits per color has a higher pixel depth than the 4-bit version.

Comment: Are you talking about how far into the "Z-plane" that the pixel resides?  Or are you talking about using a 2d projection of a 3d pixel?  Sounds like you may want to use Polar Coordinates to calculate the distance into the Z-plane.

Comment: how far into the z plane it resides

Comment: Your code would be simpler and easier to read if you made a `Point` class or a `Coordinate` class.  You could then implement the *distance formula* for however many dimensions the pixel or point has.

Comment: When displaying a 3d pixel, you'll need to figure out a [3d project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#:~:text=A%203D%20projection%20(or%20graphical,%2Ddimensional%20(2D)%20surface.&text=3D%20projections%20use%20the%20primary,to%20create%20a%20visual%20element.).  This is very important, as it determines how the Z-plane is interpreted (often termed as the camera position or angle).

Comment: do you think if I want to find the depth of a point, I could take the z axis and for each point created and do some division to find the amount of steps to get to that point 2 from point 1 and increment a variable every loop through by the value of that and then take the depth and set it to the variable each time?

Comment: I recommend you search the internet.  There are probably better algorithms than using the distance formula, especially if you are doing things iteratively.